# WPF ListView Grouping and Repeat Header gridView

Tags: wpf

i have a listView and group descriptors to see my data (see capture1) .

[image]

I want to repeat Header Row of the grid on each "group" in the list view like capture2 below :

[image]

My xaml

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,-80">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ParcVoisinsCollectionView}" >
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView  >
                        <!--<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                                            <TextBlock Text="" Padding="5">
                                                <TextBlock.Background>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#373638" />
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#77797B" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </TextBlock.Background>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>

                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>-->

                        <GridViewColumn Header="NomParc" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NomParc}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="NomEolienne" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NomEolienne}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="TypeEolienne" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TypeEolienne}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Puissance" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Puissance}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Diametre" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Diametre}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Hauteur" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Hauteur}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="X" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PositionX}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Y" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PositionY}" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>

                <ListView.GroupStyle >
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" 
                                                        FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text=" éoliennes(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter>
                                                </ItemsPresenter>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

How can i make this ?

Comment: Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Any update on this?